# ActionBar tabs remove padding and divider

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I m a facing problem when removing divider and padding between action bar tabs. I generated styles using [this](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) and following are my values-14  entries and I testing on version above 4

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Example</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_example</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_example</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Example</item>

    <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Example.Widget</item>
</style>
 // It seems below code has no effect

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
</style>
```

For illustration purpose here is exact what I want i.e. no lines in between tabs and actionbar and almost 0 padding
[image]

Comment: it looks good imo. Can you try adding `<item name="android:actionBarDivider">@null</item>` to your theme?

Comment: yeah tried but no effect :(

Comment: You missed `<item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">`. Please see my detail answer below.

Answer (score 5):

ActionBar tab is deprecated from api 21. I recommend you using one of below approach with a toolbar.

1)[PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

2)[SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html)

As your screenshot shows I think this is implemented with toolbar and one of

[PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) or [SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html). For example you can see the sample of [Android PagerSlidingTabStrip (default Material Design)](https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip) to find out how to implement exactly what you want.

Comment: I don't want a sliding one(fixed tabs) also I am not going to target 21 which has 0 market right now will consider it in future, all I want is to remove the padding and lines

Comment: finally I used your answer with slight modification, but I am still figuring out the problem and will accept you answer if there were no better answer

Answer (score 5):

follow below example.

[THEMES FOR THE ANDROID ACTIONBAR – TABS](http://www.silverbaytech.com/2013/05/13/themes-for-the-android-actionbar-tabs/)

[ActionBar Style](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/styling-the-actionbar-part-2/)

[styling-actionbartabs](http://blog.alwold.com/2013/08/28/styling-tabs-in-the-android-action-bar/)

May be helpful for you

**Updates...**

you can change tab divider color same as your tab bg color. so this effect like you not have any divder.

```
<item name="android:actionBarDivider">@color/background</item>
```

I hope its works for you.

**Updated - 2 this for how custom design your tab view from my old code that i find today**

In android manifest add-

```
 android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
```

In style.xml create new style for tabview

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">  
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TabView</item>
    </style>    
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TabView" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/new_tab_bar</item>
</style>
```

In Drawable create new tabbar like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- UNSELECTED TAB STATE -->
  <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false">
      <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item>
          <shape>
              <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>
          </shape>
       </item>
        <!-- Bottom indicator color for the UNSELECTED tab state -->
        <item android:top="-5dp" android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp">
             <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                 <stroke android:color="#65acee" android:width="0dp"/>
             </shape>
        </item>
      </layer-list>
  </item>
  <!-- SELECTED TAB STATE -->
  <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false">
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <!-- Tab background color for the SELECTED tab state -->
       <item>
          <shape>
              <solid android:color="#0099CC"/>
          </shape>
       </item>
       <!-- Bottom indicator color for the SELECTED tab state -->
       <item android:top="-5dp" android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp">
           <shape android:shape="rectangle">
               <stroke android:color="@color/tab_select_backgroung" android:width="0dp"/>
           </shape>
       </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>
</selector>
```

put change in this new_tab_bar and get what you wants changes in action bar tab.

Comment: @danny117 thanks for sugeetion see update, is ok now

Answer (score 1):

I removed the padding of the Action bar in my Project once like this, [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25120375/1515052):

configure your `AndroidManifest.xml` to use a custom Theme:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ....
    <application
        ...
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        ...
    >
    ...
    </application>
    ....
</manifest>
```

Define your custom Theme in `res/values/`**`styles`**`.xml`

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Use a custom Application theme extending an existing AppCompat theme. -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    </style>

    <!-- customize parts of your theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- indicate that the actionBar uses a custom style and configure the link -->
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/TabBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <!-- configure your real custom style for the tab bar-->
    <style name="TabBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxWidth">15dp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

The following should be placed in `res/values/`**`styles-v11`**`.xml` and `res/values/`**`styles-v14`**`.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/TabBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="TabBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxWidth">15dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android api 21 and above

Add `app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"` and `app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"` to TabLayout.
It works for me.

`<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
     android:id="@+id/tabs"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:tabGravity="fill"
     app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
     app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
     app:tabIndicatorColor="#FF0000"
     app:tabMode="fixed" />`

and add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to parent layout

Answer (score 0):

Sounded like you wanted to use 'static tab', not the newer 'sliding tab' underneath the ActionBar. From your original style 'Theme.Example' code above, I think it was missing an item that deals with ActionBar Tab Divider: **actionBarTabBarStyle**. Please see below, hope that helps.

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
    ...
    <!-- SOLUTION-2: Add this item HERE! -->
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTabBarStyle.Example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <!-- SOLUTION-0: ActionBar Navigation Tabs. 
         Original code. It has NO effect on the 'divider' style -->
    <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>

    <!-- SOLUTION-1: Add drawable background HERE!. The item element below 
         is the styling for the 'Tab', which in the form of drawable 
         styling, you could code in such a way it would overwrite the 
         default 'divider' style as described by @lokesh answer -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/new_tab_bar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabBarStyle.Example" parent="android:style/Widget.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <!-- SOLUTION-2: ALTERNATIVELY, This is for Actionbar Navigation 
         Tabs 'DIVIDER' Style. Now you can try to disable/hide them. -->
    <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">0dp</item>
</style>
```